# Getting user data from backed and displaying it on the account screen

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am trying to fetch the data of the user that is logged in and display their information in the profile screen.

This the backend code that is sending the GET request to /me

```
router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("-password");
  res.send(user);
});
```

This is the AuthContext page where the fetchUser function is located in. I want to fetch the users data.

```
const fetchUser = dispatch => async () => {
  const response = await sellerApi.get("/api/users/me");
  console.log(response.data);
  dispatch({ type: "fetch_user", payload: response.data });
};
```

If there is anything else you need to see let me know please.

Comment: What does the `console.log(response.data)` log?

Comment: @Sami Whats the problem you are facing?? Any error??

Comment: No, I am a self though developer and just recently learned react-native. I am trying to pass the users' data so when the user logs in their profile page consist of their info.

Comment: I am okay with sharing the code if needed

Comment: if you are fetchig correctly then whats the problem?